# How show flash error messages in Rails 3 using Ajax and jQuery?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

My controller is:

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:group])

  @group.company=current_user.company
  respond_to do |format|
    if @group.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@group, :notice => 'Group was successfully created.') }
      format.js
    else
      flash.now[:error]=@group.errors.full_messages
      format.html { render :nothing => true }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb is:

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @group))%>').appendTo('#groups');
$("#new_group")[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(".flashnotice").html("<%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice]) %>");  
$(".flashnotice").show(300);
```

You have to add these two lines in your `create.js.erb` file. Replace `.flashnotice` with the selector for your flash HTML element; e.g., the class name of your flash `<div>`.

Comment: I think with this approach you want `<% flash.discard %>` after showing the notice to keep the notice from appearing on subsequent pages.

Answer (score -4):

I think you just need to say `<%= flash[:notice] %>` somewhere in your erb file.